# VSCode - Disable autocomplete only for backspace key (and delete)

Tags: visual-studio-code

Whenever I type the quotation marks `"` VSCode automatically inserts two of them. E.g. `"<CURSOR_HERE>"`. Which I think is fine.

But whenever I delete one of the quotation marks, it deletes both. This is not fine.

Does VSCode support it that removing characters with backspace (or delete) does not trigger "auto complete".

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

- Tools
- Options
- Text editor
- C# or whichever language you are using
- General
- Uncheck 'Automatic brace completion'

Comment: Where is "Tools"? I have a cog in the left corner and from there I can go to "Settings"? Also wouldn't this disable the automatic completion completely, and not only for backspacing?